# Regex to get 2nd or 3rd level domain with path in it

Tags: regex

I created this regex: `[^.]*\.[^.]{2,3}(?:\.[^.]{2,3})?$`

Given: `https://this.is.my.nice.service.co.uk`

My regex will return: `service.co.uk`

But it will not work for: `https://this.is.my.nice.service.co.uk/sample`

I would like my regex to always return the 2nd or 3rd level domain regardless if there's a path or not.

So given `https://this.is.my.nice.service.co.uk` and `https://this.is.my.nice.service.co.uk/sample` the result should be: `service.co.uk`.

How can I achieve that?

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kygHUa/1

Comment: You can make use of  capture group `([^.]*\.[^.]{2,3}(?:\.[^.]{2,3})?)(?:/\S*)?$` or a lookahead assertion `[^.]*\.[^.]{2,3}(?:\.[^.]{2,3})?(?=(?:/\S*)?$)` https://regex101.com/r/e9o7ii/1

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird ! that worked! I was also wondering, could you help me fixing the fact that if I use only `https://service.co.uk/sample` it won't work as expected? https://regex101.com/r/US5kWy/1 it's basically returning: `https://service.co.uk`. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: That is because the `.` matches any character. You might exclude characters that are not allowed to match `[^/]*\.[^.]{2,3}(?:\.[^.]{2,3})?(?=(?:/\S*)?$)`

Comment: I updated it https://regex101.com/r/9u5wiQ/1 there was a bug on the previous one you shared, buy my solution was based on yours. Thanks!

Comment: You can omit the pipe in the leading negated character class. Note that it can also match spaces and newlines. If you don't want to match those `[^./\s]*\.[^\s.]{2,3}(?:\.[^.\s]{2,3})?(?=(?:\/\S*)?$)`

Comment: Got you! Would it be also possible to avoid the final slash from `service.co.uk/` ? https://regex101.com/r/HhEw73/1 I'm learning a lot!

Comment: You can also specify what you want to match like `\b\w+(?:\.\w{2,3}){1,2}(?=(?:/\S*)?$)` or exclude the forward slashes `[^./\s/]*(?:\.[^\s./]{2,3}){1,2}(?=(?:\/\S*)?$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example strings, you can exclude matching the dot and forward slash, and optionally assert `/` followed by optional non whitespace chars till the end of the string.

Then get the first match, in case pattern can match multiple times in the string.

```
[^./\s/]*(?:\.[^\s./]{2,3}){1,2}(?=(?:\/\S*)?$)
```

See a [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ijc9U3/1).

```js
const regex = /[^./\s/]*(?:\.[^\s./]{2,3}){1,2}(?=(?:\/\S*)?$)/;
[
  "https://this.is.my.nice.service.co.uk",
  "https://service.co.uk",
  "https://this.is.my.nice.service.co.uk/sample",
  "https://service.com",
  "https://this.is.my.nice.service.co.uk/"
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[0]);
  }
});
```

If all the parts start with `https://` you could make the pattern a bit more specific, starting with the protocol and optional non greedy repetitions of the allowed characters followed by a dot.

Then get the capture group 1 value.

```
https?:\/\/(?:[^./\s/]*\.)*?([^./\s/]*(?:\.[^\s./]{2,3}){1,2}(?=(?:\/\S*)?$))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4nRBiy/1)